# how to build up UITableViewController with different Prototype Cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I Added the UI Tableview, 
and created unique Prototype Cell for each one:

[image]

I Attached UItableview cells to the unique Prototype Cells and gave each cell an identifier in the storyboard (also i put functions in each class to change the text, etc in that specific cell)

[image]

In my main UITableViewController, 
I set the size to a costume value that i change later,

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return tableSectionsSize
}
```

My question now is how do i setup the screen itself, 
with all i want and with the headlines and everything?

All the tutorials i find is for one tableview with all the data in the same kind, but in my case i have 8 different Prototype Cell.

Can u refer me to a tutorial for what I want to achieve? 
Or explain to me how I can build up the data itself when i have different Prototype Cell and i want to show\hide each one of them ?

Comment: By 8 different sections do you mean you have 8 different cells? In that case, you only need 1 section

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://briterideas.com/blog_images/tableviews/part3/repeated_rows.png
You can clearly see there are 3 sections. Each section has 3 rows. They do have the same data, but the cells could be different. See a section as a group of cells

Comment: @Craz1k0ek i actually mean 8 different prototype Cells, indeed that is correct. but i want to know how to show each Prototype cell, and how i could build it with different prototype cell types

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to `cells` and not `sections`.

All the tutorials you find are talking about `Dynamic Prototypes` kind of cells. By the `Prototype Cells` that appears in your image, that's what your `UITableView` is using. So the first thing is to switch it to `Static Cells` in the `Attribute Inspector`:

[image: Setting Static Cells in TableView's Attribute Inspector]

Then, add and customize each one of your `TableViewCell's` as you already did. Add as much labels, buttons, switches, etc as you like. They'll be shown in the `Document Outliner` as follows. You should now have 8 custom cells.

[image: Custom Cells inside UITableView]

If you wish to group them logically, you should do as Craz1k0ek mentioned and separate them in sections, also in the `Attribute Inspector`, dragging the cells to their corresponding sections.

No need to use `numberOfSections(in tableView:)` method here.

I hope this helps.

Comment: that won't help as i have a veriable amount of data inserted, and it's not a static thing that i always know what to show and how it looks,

Answer (score 0):

For tables, we got a method cellForAtIndexPath. Here according to your logic , you can choose and configure cell and then return it.

But if your layout is not gonna change, then it's better to use static tables. In static tables design your cells beforehand. It will work fine.

Comment: yea but my content is changing dynamicaly

Comment: Then you can choose and configure according to your logic and return that cell from cellForAtIndexPath message. Then type cast it back to cell of specific type to access it's properties. For this again you need to apply the same 'Logic'

Comment: do you know how would i add the separator headlines between the individual cells ?  @user8950495

Comment: I am not getting you. do you want to insert label ? or do you want to include lines?

Comment: I mean i have the different cell types and i want to know how to devide between them and add a headline in between, how would i do that ?

Comment: @ChiefMadog do you mean as in "Animals" and "Birds" in this image? http://iamyash.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/TableViewSection_Swift4-1200x675.jpg

Comment: @CarlosKochhann yes exactly !

Comment: @ChiefMadog Ok, those two are called sections in a `Dynamic Prototypes` type TableView. You then need to use `tableView.register` to all your 8 cells and defines which one should take place using `tableView(_: cellForRowAt:)`

Comment: @CarlosKochhann i'm not sure exactly on where do i say in code that this is a section and what is the header etc, but i'll post now another question and maybe u can answer that ?

Comment: @ChiefMadog sure!